# In Spring, can I autowire a property value simply by including that JAR in my WAR file?

Tags: spring, properties, autowired, properties-file

I’m using Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE.  I have a JAR file with a class that has the following

```
@Service(“myService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService
{

    …    
    @Value(“#{myProperties[‘my.properties.key’]}”)
    private String myPropertiesValue;
```

When I include the JAR file in a WAR, I must put this in the WAR’s application context or else the autowiring fails …

```
<util:properties id=“myProperties" location="classpath:my_file.properties" />
```

The file “my_file.properties” is at the root of my JAR file.  My question is, is there any way I can get the autowiring of the property to occur by simply including my JAR file in my WAR?  I realize that adding ‘<util:properties id=“myProperties" location="classpath:my_file.properties" />’ is not that hard, but when I include the above JAR in dozens of projects, it is easy to forget to include the “util” declaration in one or two, causing those applications to fail to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other conceptually different way. Either you include the properties or you can import full xml which defines part of the application context specific to this jar:

```
<import resource="classpath:my_jar_config.xml" />
```

where `my_jar_config.xml` contains all beans and the `<util:properties>` specific to this jar.

Comment: But in your example I would have to import the "my_jar_config.xml" in every WAR where i include that JAR, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I believe it's good idea to have kind of explicit control over the resources as you still have option to include this jar because you'd like to reuse data classes...